# How can I create a custom project layout based on another eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

My ultimate goal is to create an eclipse plugin that sets up a PDT project, but with some added builders (and custom build scripts) as well as a specific folder layout (and different folders should be treated as source and some as regular folders).

I've looked at / followed eclipse plugin development tutorials, and ok. I get the gist of creating a wizard that creates a file, but I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to create a project, and more importantly, make that project associated with the PDT (PHP Development Tools) feature.

Answer:

I did stumble upon a solution myself before the answer was given, but it's quite similar.

First, `WizardNewProjectCreationPage` was used as the first page of my wizard.

Second, on `performFinish()` I ran the following code:

```java
        IProgressMonitor    m           = new NullProgressMonitor();
        IWorkspaceRoot      root        = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
        IProject            project     = root.getProject(_pageOne.getProjectName());

        if (!project.exists())
        {
            IProjectDescription desc = project.getWorkspace().newProjectDescription(project.getName());
            URI projectLocation = _pageOne.getLocationURI();
            // desc.setLocationURI(projectLocation);

            String[]            natures     = desc.getNatureIds();
            String[]            newNatures  = new String[natures.length + 1];

            System.arraycopy(natures, 0, newNatures, 0, natures.length);
            newNatures[natures.length] = PHPNature.ID;

            desc.setNatureIds(newNatures);
            project.create(desc, m);
            project.open(m);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to create a project

Take a look at [`BasicNewProjectResourceWizard.createNewProject()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6/org.eclipse.ui/ide/3.6.0/org/eclipse/ui/wizards/newresource/BasicNewProjectResourceWizard.java#BasicNewProjectResourceWizard.createNewProject%28%29) method.

> make that project associated with the PDT (PHP Development Tools) feature

You need to add "org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature" to the project (that's what *Add PHP Support...* action does). Use [`IProjectDescription.setNatureIds()`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IProjectDescription.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've edited my question to show what I did to accomplish what I wanted. I stumbled upon it myself, and is almost identical to what you describe. I was simply not aware of how natures worked ;)